# Bootstrap + vertical menubar + with collapse button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Is there anyway to keep the 480 & 768 Pixel screen views in a bootstrap as the default view even for default and large displays 940PX and above?
My requirement is to have the vertical nav menu with Toggle button (View when display size is < 768Pixel) even for the default and larger screens as shown 
in this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/18x9J.png

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.**

On the [Bootstrap's customization page](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=b1ab50adbf26141c142b#grid-system) change the `@grid-float-breakpoint` parameter to `@screen-lg-min`, then download the new source (add the end of the page) and replace the bootstrap.css file (and/or the minified version) of your project with the downloaded one.